# bootstrap 2.3.2 floating columns with same height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make my two columns having the same height on large devices?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span10 content pull-right"></div>
        <div class="span2 sidebar pull-left"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). That article provides a complete rundown of all of the options available to you.